# how to add extra column from an existing .text file in wso2 esb?

Tags: wso2-esb

I have Input.text file which has following values

```
**SNO|FIRSTNAME|LASTNAME|EMAIL|PHONE|ADDRESS|SELLING_DEALER**
**51|chris|clark|cpar@hotmail.com|0406-755789|Australia|MB MacGregor**
```

I have done some operation like phone validation or email validation.After performing that,**need to write output file** which has following values if phonevalidation gets successed.

```
**SNO|FIRSTNAME|LASTNAME|EMAIL|PHONE|ADDRESS|SELLING_DEALER|PHONEVALIDATION**
**51|chris|clark|cpar@hotmail.com|0406-755789|Australia|MB MacGregor|yes**
```

Otherwise(if phonevalidation gets failed)

```
**SNO|FIRSTNAME|LASTNAME|EMAIL|PHONE|ADDRESS|SELLING_DEALER|PHONEVALIDATION**
**51|chris|clark|cpar@hotmail.com|0406-755789|Australia|MB MacGregor|No**
```

Hope you understood my question!
Anyone please help me out to find solution,
*Awaiting for your response*

Comment: What do you use to read and validate the input file?

Comment: Hi @ophychius,
I am reading input .text file using inbound-Endpoint,then for validation,i am using some API call,which provides some JSON response as output whether it is valid or Not.i have done reading input file and validation  part in my project.So now i just need to write/add extra column which was mentioned above to existing file.Please help me to append extra column with values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Depending on PHONEVALIDATION, you can route the payload using **Router Mediator** and later on enrich youy payload using Enrich Mediator.

How to enrich payload take a look this post (https://dzone.com/articles/wso2-esb-enrich-mediator-fast)

Hope this helps